# QuerySet is empty when try to get User from multiple databases

Tags: django, django-database

I have a project with multiple databases. I'm trying to fetch all users from one of databases like this:

```
users = User.objects.using('mydb').all()
```

or this:

```
users = User.objects.db_manager('mydb').all()
```

but get an empty query list instead. `<QuerySet [<User: >]>`

I've test this with some other models but they are working grate.
Also when I've get the count of my records, return the correct number of records.

Am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `QuerySet` is not empty, it contains a single `User`, and that user likely has no username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but get an empty query list instead. `<QuerySet [<User: >]>`

The `QuerySet` is ***not* empty**. Indeed: it has a *single* `User`, notice the `<User: >` part. That user only seems to have an empty `username`, the `<User: >` is the `repr(..)` of that single user. For example:

```
>>> User(username='')
<User: >
```

You can iterate over it, for example:

```
for user in User.objects.using('mydb').all():
    print('a user')
```

and it will print `'a user'` once.